# How to document json/js object for intellisense in vscode?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, javascript-objects, jsdoc

I am working on a project in which I'd like to define a simple js object.

This object is important so I'd like to document it so that vscode's intellisense describes it accurately (description, type and value).

I tried to use the `@type` property but intellisense keeps showing `any` and ignores it.

```
module.exports = {
    /**
     * Output file.
     *
     * @type {String}
     * @default null
     */
     'output': null
};
```

Both `@type` and `@default` are ignored by intellisense even though they show as valid color-wise.

I tried with and without brackets around the type.

How would I do it properly?